# Datatables: How do I get the row with certain cell value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Below is the table I've created:

```
var table= $("#mytable").DataTable({

    ajax: "list.json",
    columns: [
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "location"},
        {"data": "date"}
    ]
});
```

Now I want to edit the `location` in the row where the `name` is "John" for example. I've tried to go this way:

```
table.search("John").column(0).row(0).cell(1).data(" New location ");
```

But this doesn't work for the reason unknown to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows) // Search whole table
{
    if(dr["name"] == "John") // If name== 'John'
    {
        dr["location"] = "New location"; //Change the location
        //break;
    }
    else if()
    {
      // Do Something else
    }
}
```